# Unlimited Display of Data

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

My app is written in ASP.NET Core. I have five hundred rows, however, my browser only displays 50 rows give or take.

How do I increase the display limit? Additionally I am using Razor pages not MVC.

I have tried `[RequestFormLimits(ValueCountLimit = 100000)]` and does nothing.

Comment: Question too vague to pin point. There is no limitation applied as such to block display of records. You can start by Checking your Model and see how many records are actually returned. Maybe you have a pagination plugin which has the page selection hidden.

Comment: Do also share your code sample to assist if the above process didnt help.

Comment: Why did you think `RequestFormLimits` has anything to do with data display, or that browsers cap the amount of data that can be displayed? You seem to making assumptions without doing even the most basic investigation.